# select2-selecting event not getting fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jquery-select2, backbone-events

I am using [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#documentation) in my website, and I'm trying to use the `select2-selecting` event, but its not firing. I am also using [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) in the app, so the first thing I tried was adding the `select2-selecting` to my `events` object:

```
// 'change .city':'cityChanged'
'select2-selecting .city':'cityChanged'
```

Note that I have a `change` event commented out - this `change` event works properly. In the documentation for [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#documentation), the `select2-selecting` event is put directly on the object, not like this:

```
$('.city').select2().on('select2-selecting', function(e){ 
     console.log('here');
});
```

instead, its supposed to be used like this:

```
$('.city').on('select2-selecting', function(e){ 
     console.log('here');
});
```

I have also tried adding the event both of these ways, but the event didn't fire (I did check and the element was created on the DOM **before** I added the events).

When I add the event in the first method with the [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/), the event is listed in the event listeners in the chrome debug console - it just doesn't get fired. Does anyone have an idea what is going on?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

what version of `select2` are you using?

I was having the same problem until I realize I was using the 3.3 version where this `select2-selecting` event not exists.

This has been included in the 3.4 version.

Comment: i'm using select2 3.4.3 and i have the same problem none of the events are triggered !!

Answer (score 12):

There was a change on earlier versions also where it changes name:

- select2-close is now select2:close
- select2-open is now select2:open
- select2-opening is now select2:opening
- select2-selecting is now select2:selecting
- select2-removed is now select2:removed
- select2-removing is now select2:unselecting

Comment: This is correct for 3.5, no idea why the documentation does not include this.....

Answer (score 0):

On even older versions, '**select2-removed**' and '**select2-removing**' events listed on [@santi-iglesias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32953600/4265572)' answer **doesn't exists**. You have '**removed**' instead. Also, to get the affected optioin value, use '**event.val**'.

So you can do something like this:

```
$('.select').on('select2-selecting removed', function(evt) {
    var value = evt.val; //do something with this
});
```

Checked at v3.4.3.